# yii2 GridView many to many junction table display

Tags: gridview, yii2

Classic tables: User, auth_item (for roles/permissions), auth_assignment junction for many-to-many Users<->Roles.

I followed (or tried to follow) the documentation and other people' questions. I came up with the following (I have an "Ar" prefix for my classes for my ActiveRecord tests):

In "user" model (models/Aruser.php):

```
public function getRoles() {
    return $this->hasMany(ArauthItem::className(), ['name' => 'item_name'])
      ->viaTable('auth_assignment', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In "roles" model, aka auth_item table model (models/ArauthItem.php):

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Aruser::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
      ->viaTable('auth_assignment', ['item_name' => 'name']);
}
```

In "user search" model (models/ArusersSearch.php):

```
class AruserSearch extends Aruser{  
public $roles;    

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['username', 'auth_key', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email','roles'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Aruser::find();
    $query->joinWith(['roles']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

   /* ... some skipped code, the usual ... */

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_key', $this->auth_key])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_hash', $this->password_hash])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'password_reset_token', $this->password_reset_token])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'auth_item.name', $this->roles]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}

And finally, in the view file:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        'auth_key',
        'password_hash',
        'password_reset_token', 
        'roles.name',

        /*
        [
         'attribute' => 'roles',
         // this is an anonymous function built by me to retrieve correct concatanated related m to n values, but is it the proper and correct way?
         'value' => function ($model) {     
                    $multiple_res = '';
                    foreach($model->roles as $role){
                        $multiple_res .= ($multiple_res?',':'').$role->name;
                    }
                    return $multiple_res;
                },              
         ],
         */

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

I cannot make the Roles column to show anything but "(not set)", unless I use the anonymous function you can see commented above. What is the Yii2>GridView  way of displaying many-to-many concatanated in one column? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an anonymous function is the correct way. Yii doesn't support the function you speak of as far as I know.

But I would simplify your function like so:

```
'value' => function($model) {
    return implode(", ", array_map(function($ar){
            return $ar->name;
    }, $model->roles));
}
```

Comment: Thank you ttdijkstra, just a small comment: implode doesn't apply here, $model->roles is an array of array

Comment: Point taken. How careless of me.

Comment: Thank you ttdijkstra, that was helpful .